# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Buttons' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm having a small error on my website. I'd like to host the website using github so I linked my scripts in my HTML like this:

```
    <script src="assets/scripts/switch-content.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/scroll-fade.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/scroll-top-load.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/shrinking-header.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/smooth scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/burger-menu.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/card-flip.js"></script>
```

and most of them work but for some reason my burger menu for the mobile version and the script that changes the content of the site when clicked on a button won't work.

Is there any false code here or could it be because of jquery which won't load correctly?
I tried linking the script separately and like I did below.

codes that don't work:

```
// change activenav class, show the clicked element only and hide the others https://codepen.io/MohdHussein/pen/MWKEvdp


// grab all the buttons
let Buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".selectSection button");

// loop through the buttons using for..of 
for (let button of Buttons) {
  // listen for a click event 
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // et = event target
    const et = e.target;
    // slect activenav class
    const activenav = document.querySelector(".activenav");
    // check for the button that has activenav class and remove it
    if (activenav) {
      activenav.classList.remove("activenav");
    }
    // add activenav class to the clicked element 
    et.classList.add("activenav");

    // select all classes with the name content
    let allContent = document.querySelectorAll('.contentsec');

    // loop through all content classes
    for (let contentsec of allContent) {
      // display the content if the class has the same data-attribute as the button 
      if (contentsec.getAttribute('data-number') === button.getAttribute('data-number')) {
        contentsec.style.display = "block";
      }
      // if it's not equal then hide it.
      else {
        contentsec.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    this.fade(true); //Call fade method on click 
  });
}
```

```
$('.flip-container .flipper button').click(function() {
  // flip back previous hovered element
  $('.flip-container.hover').toggleClass('hover');
  // flip current element
  $(this).closest('.flip-container').toggleClass('hover');
});

$('.fbutton').click(function() {
  // flip current element
  $(this).closest('.flip-container').removeClass('hover');
});
```

```
let burger = document.getElementById('burger'),
     nav    = document.getElementById('main-nav'),
     slowmo = document.getElementById('slowmo');
   
burger.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    this.classList.toggle('is-open');
    nav.classList.toggle('is-open');
});

$(".main-nav").click(function(){
  burger.click();
})
```

Comment: This is one of the joys of global variables, just don't use global variables.

Comment: So where do I start to fix this? I'm kinda new to this :)

Comment: The error message tells you where the variable has been previously declared, or just rename the variable in this script.

Comment: Alright, thank you! Will try this

Comment: I changed the variable of "buttons" and there's no actual error on the page but it still won't work. [image](https://imgur.com/a/nPj75ty)

Comment: It all worked in my JSFiddle btw but for some reason when importing it to github it stop working

Comment: Probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) ...

Comment: This didn't do it for me. I tried prioritizing the scripts that don't work but it didn't do much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to see the contents of your other scripts we can't identify the problem for you.

Suffice it to say *somewhere* in script you have declared another JS variable called **Buttons**

You could just rename this instance, but as pointed out in the comments, this is a side effect of using global variables. A better approach is  to use an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) pattern to avoid polluting global scope

Sounds complicated but its as simple as this:

```
  <script>
    (function () {
          // grab all the buttons
    let Buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".selectSection button");
    
    // loop through the buttons using for..of 
    for (let button of Buttons) {
      // listen for a click event 
      button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        // et = event target
        const et = e.target;
        // slect activenav class
        const activenav = document.querySelector(".activenav");
        // check for the button that has activenav class and remove it
        if (activenav) {
          activenav.classList.remove("activenav");
        }
        // add activenav class to the clicked element 
        et.classList.add("activenav");
    
        // select all classes with the name content
        let allContent = document.querySelectorAll('.contentsec');
    
        // loop through all content classes
        for (let contentsec of allContent) {
          // display the content if the class has the same data-attribute as the button 
          if (contentsec.getAttribute('data-number') === button.getAttribute('data-number')) {
            contentsec.style.display = "block";
          }
          // if it's not equal then hide it.
          else {
            contentsec.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
        this.fade(true); //Call fade method on click 
      });
    }
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this didn't work unfortunately. The script I used worked perfectly fine in my JSFiddle but when uploaded in github it stops working

Comment: I edited the code and added all the scripts that don't work

Comment: So if you dont have an error in your console, there's probably a logic error in your code. You can debug that https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Is highly possible the `Buttons` variable is declared somewhere in these loaded scripts.

```
    <script src="assets/scripts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/scroll-fade.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/scroll-top-load.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/shrinking-header.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/smooth scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/switch-content.js"></script>
```